# Probability of red cabs

Tags: probability

> In a country, there are $30\%$ blue cabs and $70\%$ red cabs. One night, an accident occurred. The witness says the cab involved was red. But a psychologist testifies that there is a $10\%$ he might mistaken blue cab to red cab and also a $10\%$ to have mistaken a red cab to a blue cab.
>
> 1. What is the probability that the cab involved was red?
> 2. Suppose that the witness had identified the cab involved as being blue rather than red. What is the probability that the cab involved in the accident was blue?

**Attempt:**
1) $P(\text{Red}) = 0.7, P(\text{Blue}) = 0.3 $
$P(\text{Not mistaken}|\text{Red}) = 0.9 , P(\text{Not mistaken}|\text{Blue}) = 0.9$ 
\begin{align*}
P(\text{Not mistaken}) &= P(\text{Red})P(\text{Not mistaken}|\text{Red}) +  P(\text{Blue})P(\text{Not mistaken}|\text{Blue})\\
&= 0.7 \cdot 0.9 + 0.3 \cdot 0.9 = 0.9
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
P(\text{Red}|\text{not mistaken}) &= \frac{P(\text{Not mistaken}|\text{Red})  P(R)}{P(\text{Not Mistaken})}\\
&= \frac{0.9\cdot 0.7}{0.9} \\
&= 0.7
\end{align*}

But answer shows it's $0.9$.

Answer (score 1):

You are asked for the probability of red given that the witness reported red.  The witness can report red because the cab is red and the ID is correct, with probability $0.7 \cdot 0.9=0.63$ or because the cab is blue and the ID is incorrect with probability $0.3 \cdot 0.1=0.03$.  Given the red ID, the chance the cab really is red is then $\frac {0.63}{0.63+0.03}=\frac {21}{22}\approx 0.95$

Answer (score 0):

do it with a tree

RED crash 0.7
reports red = 0.7 x .9 = .63
reports blue = 0.7 x 0.1 = .07

BLUE crash 0.3
reports red = .3 x .1 = .03
reports blue = .3 x .9 = .27

1) of the .63 + .03 = .66 chance of a red report, .63 of them are red
P = .63 / .66 = 21 / 22

2) of the .07 + .27 = .34 reports of 'BLUE', .27 are actually blue
P = .27 / .34 = 27 / 34